# vim shortcut for keyboard combo and a function call

Tags: vim

I have a Vim function (written by somebody else) that runs the highlighted visual block as a script in another program. I have a keybinding (`F9`) for it so I can call it with a visual block of lines.

I would like to further automatize things by creating specific shortcuts to two tasks:

- Visually select here from to the beginning of the document and call the function.
- Visually select the current line and call the function.

I don't necessarily need to use a macro, but I tried to use macros to do this. So added something like

`:let @r='0vgg<F9>'`

to my `.vimrc` for the first task. And when try to run it, it seems to highlight the right area, but the function call never happens.

How would you suggest I create these shortcuts successfully?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should take a look the function, if it supports `range`. If true, you don't have to do visual selection. you could:

```
nnoremap <F7> :1,.call YourFunction()<cr>
nnoremap <F8> :.call YourFunction()<cr>
```

so, the `<F7>` would call the function with range from line1 till current line. `<F8>` will call the function on current line.

If you want to define a macro, you have to escape the `<f9>`:

```
:let @r="0vgg\<F9>"
```

otherwise, vim thinks you pressed `< f 9 and >`

Comment: I don't think this function can handle ranges. But your correction of my macro works great. thanks!