# How to rebase without intermediate commit on Git?

Tags: git

When I work on a branch, before to push the changes, I squash my single local commit in this way:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'x'
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
# here I choose the option 'f' in the VI editor for the commit 'x' 
# to keep the comment from the first and save `:wq`
```

and finally update remote commit

```
$ push -f
```

Is there a way to avoid the above steps commit/rebase/choose-f/save/exit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I squash my last N commits together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-do-i-squash-my-last-n-commits-together) --> use `git merge --squash`

Comment: I use that when I merge from the main branch so I do not think is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the steps commit+rebase+choose-f+save+exit to this single command:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

You can make an alias if you do this frequently:

```
git config --global alias.fixup "commit --amend --no-edit"
```

and use it like this:

```
git fixup
```

Answer (score 0):

You would needs to write a script which can chain commands resulting in what you need.

That script would:

- [get the comment of the last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413284/6309): `git show -s --format=%s`
- `git reset --soft @{u}` (the remote tracking upstream branch) moving HEAD to the last time you pushed that branch.
  (same idea as in "[squash unpushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869737/6309)")
- add, and commit using the saved comment message from above.
- `push -f`

That script can then be called from vim as [a function mapped to key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451506/6309)